# "Whole my family", "All my family"

Tags: prepositions

I have read text about how to use **all** and **whole** but I still do not understand it. Can you tell me, please, when to use 1st type and when to use 2nd type and give me some exampleas.

I am not a student and this is not my homework.

> **All** my family was on holiday in Spain last summer.

or

> **Whole** my family was on holiday in Spain last summer.

Comment: It would be "my whole family..." for the second one. The first one is correct, though you can also say "all of my family..."

Answer (score 2):

The word "whole" may be an adjective meaning including all components without exception, and then it should follow the pronoun:

> My whole family was on holiday in Spain last summer;

or it may be a noun meaning "all of something including all its component elements or parts", and then it should be used as  "the whole of something":

> The whole of my family was on holiday in Spain last summer.

The word "all" may be a quantifier or a plural pronoun meaning all people and you can use ***all my family*** or ***all of my family*** in accordance with your preference.

To me, all the above seem pretty much the same. Anyway, [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+whole+of+my+family%2Cmy+whole+family%2Call+my+family%2Call+of+my+family&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20whole%20of%20my%20family%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20whole%20family%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20my%20family%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20of%20my%20family%3B%2Cc0) accepts all of them indicating the rarest usage of "the whole of my family" and the most frequent "my whole family"

Comment: @Man_From_India: "whole can never be a noun, neither it's an adjective ". [Yes, it can](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/whole).

Answer (score 1):

The first is correct, because "all (of)" identifies what percentage of your family you are talking about:

> All *(of)* my family was on holiday in Spain last summer.

Compare to:

> Half *(of)* my family was on holiday in Spain last summer.

The second is wrong, because "whole" must modify *family*, not *my*:

> My whole family was on holiday in Spain last summer.

Comment: To be clear, the expressions are "All of my ..." and "My whole/entire ..."